# PHP constructor arguments?

Tags: php

I'm building a class that needs two arguments, and they can be passed through `__constructor`, or they can be set using setter methods.

What is the best way to check if arguments are passed through constructor?

I did it like this:

```
class Services {

    public function __construct(array $configs, array $services)
    {
        if(isset($configs) AND isset($services)) {
            $this->configs = $configs;
            $this->services = $services;
        }
    }

    public function setConfigs(array $configs)
    {
        $this->config = $configs;
    }

    public function setServices(array $services)
    {
        $this->services = $services;
    }
}
```

Now this works fine, but I'm not 100% if  this is the right way.
The thing thats bothering me is that if arguments are passed through constructor, I want both of them there, not only one.

How would I prevent user to put only one argument in constructor?

Answer (score 5):

Currently you *have* to pass two arguments. To make them optional, you need to assign default values. You can then enforce both with a simple check:

```
public function __construct(array $configs = null, array $services = null) {
    if ($configs === null xor $services === null) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Supply both or none!');
    }
    if ($configs && $services) {
        $this->setConfigs($configs);
        $this->setServices($services);
    }
}
```

You shouldn't use `isset`, since the *variable* always exists, as it's part of the function signature. You only need to check the values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested it? When you have defined the types in the function header  `__construct(array $configs, array $services)`, you ensure that a user MUST pass two arrays!

```
$test = new Services(array());
```

fails - Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Services::__construct() must be an array

```
$test = new Services('','');
```

Fails - Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Services::__construct() must be an array,

only

```
$test = new Services(array(), array());
```

is allowed!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the php `is_null()` function, so if `!is_null(arg1) && !is_null(arg2)`, then you're fine.

Comment: How about `!(is_null(arg1) || is_null(arg2))`?

Comment: It gets the same result, and the code is equally long.
So both ways are correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Seperately handle the arguments you passed.

```
public function __construct(array $configs, array $services)
{
    if(isset($configs)) {
        $this->configs = $configs;
    }
    if(isset($services)) {
        $this->services = $services;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
public function __construct(array $configs = false, array $services = false)
    {
        if($configs && $services) {
            $this->configs = $configs;
            $this->services = $services;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would rather not doing this, it is better to don't mix type, you should use `array $configs = array()` to allow no value to be set.